# Grails, Jquery, SubmitToRemote: how do I Update the next div?

Tags: jquery, grails

I'm using a template to render Posts and Comments on my Grails 2.0.3 application. When the page loads or reloads, all of the post's comments are under the correct posts.  But when a user comments on a post, (using submitToRemote) the div that is updated is the first div on the page with the id specified in the submitToRemote 'update' parameter. (the most recent post)  I'd like it to use the 'next' div, instead of hard coding a div name into the submitToRemote update parameter. Below is the template...

```
<div class="postBox2">

<div class="postContent">
<h1>${post.user.username} said</h1> 
    <div class="status3">
        ${post.content }
    </div>
</div>

<g:if test="{post.postComments}">
    <div class="postCommentsBox">
        <div class="postCommentForm">   
            <g:form>
                <g:hiddenField name="thePost" value="${post?.id}" />
                <g:textArea id="postComment" name="content" placeholder="Comment here"/>
                <g:submitToRemote value="Post"
                    url="[controller: 'postComment', action: 'saveCommentWithService']"
                    update="postCommentsBox"
                    onSuccess="clearPost(data)"
                    onLoading="showSpinner(true)"
                    onComplete="showSpinner(false)"
                    />

                <g:img id="spinner" style="display: none" uri="/images/spinner.gif"/>
            </g:form>       
        </div>  

        <div id="postCommentsBox">
        <g:each in="${post.postComments}" var="pc"> 
            <div class="status3">
                <g:link controller="user" action="show" id="${pc.userCreator.id}">${pc.userCreator.username }</g:link> said 
                <br />
                ${pc.content }
            </div>
        </g:each>
        </div>

    </div>  
</g:if>
```

My question is: how can I update the next div on the template instead of hardcoding a div name into the update parameter?

I've been trying variations of this:  update=this.next()
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at the submitToRemote tag, so I'm just adding this as a comment instead of an answer.  I don't know if it's even possible with that tag, but it would be trivial to do with plain jQuery.  Just have a plain button with an onclick that calls a javascript function, and in that function use jQuery to do a $.post with a callback.  You'll get full control over the results that way and as an added bonus, be more ready for future upgrades because all of the remote tags are removed from grails in later versions!

Comment: awesome!  thanks so much for the insight.  I will definitely look into doing that.  I'm new to JQuery and javascript so I'm kind of dong this blind and need to be pointed in the right direction.  thanks again